# How to mask parameters and password in Jenkins build history?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, password-protection

When using Password parameter to accept user credentials, 
Jenkins Build History -> Parameters is showing Password in plain text.

[image]

How to mask it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Mask Passwords Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin).

With this plugin, passwords don't appear as plain text in the job configuration or in the console.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regular `password` parameter type, for example using parameters defined in the jenkinsfile: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

The problem with that one is that, even if it masks the password when you access the "Parameters" section of a build and when you write it on "Build with parameters", if at any point that value is printed in the logs, it is shown.

To avoid that you have the [Mask Passwords Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin) as said previously by 
[Javier C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3739382/javier-c). The problem with that one is that the plugin at the moment of writing this answer is up for adoption and has [security vulnerabilities](https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2019-08-07/#SECURITY-157).